# Claim the video with a monetization policy Youtube .NET

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api

I founded many examples with PHP and Java, but I need to create one Web Service to Upload videos with a policy monetization on You tube, I tried this code below and others, but I don't get Upload videos and set monetization. How can I do this?

```
video.MonetizationDetails = new VideoMonetizationDetails { Access = new AccessPolicy { Allowed = true } };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Youtube .NET Guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet) as your reference. You can use [MonetizationDetails](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1YouTube_1_1v3_1_1Data_1_1VideoMonetizationDetails.html) in C#/.NET like you do in other languages. It should follow the same concept.

Comment: But with this I don't get this:

Usege Policy and Content ID matching: Enable with one my Policies

You can see my code above, this not works ;(